# Is there a way to identify which div users were viewing in a webpage and return to the same div after they resubmit the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

**use case:**
I have a jsp page with multiple **divs** within an html form. The default view in (div1) must display when the page is first loaded while (div2 and div3 are hidden).   On the initial page load each **div** contains different field data returned from a database query. A toggle function was implemented to show/hide **divs** and triggered by the user's selection view preference.  After the form is submitted again by the user, jsp returns additional data to each div.

**problem**:
I need a way to have the web page identify which **div** the user was viewing and return to the same **div** in the page after they resubmit another database query bypassing the default view in (**div 1**).

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Below is an excerpt I am testing:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#div1').click(function() {
    $('.div1').toggle(700);

    if ($('.div1').is(':visible')) {
      $('.div2').hide();
      $('.div3').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('#div2').click(function() {
    $('.div2').toggle(700);

    if ($('.div2').is(':visible')) {
      $('.div1').hide();
      $('.div3').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('#div3').click(function() {
    $('.div3').toggle(700);

    if ($('.div3').is(':visible')) {
      $('.div1').hide();
      $('.div2').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="div1">Default Query View 1 Data</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="div2">Query View 2 Data</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="div3">Query View 3 Data</a>
  </li>
</nav>

<body>
  <form id="jdform" name="jdform" method="post" action="testDivToggle.html">

    <div id="div1" class="div1" style="display: block;">
      <p>Default Data for View 1 query: field1,field2</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" class="div2" style="display: none;">
      <p>Queried Data from View 2 query: field3,field4,field5</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div3" class="div3" style="display: none;">
      <p>Queried Data from View 3 query: field6,field7</p>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: As a note, your `<nav>` should really be inside of your `<body>` tag. Almost everything should.

Comment: Yes, manually. Pass on which div was being viewed with the form data, or, use the history api pushstate or the url hash to store it and restore it on page load.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, just save the div number in a cookie when the user clicks/opens a div.  Then when you reload the page, enable the div based on that cookie value.  If you don't set an expiration, the cookie will go away when the user closes their browser, which I assume should be fine in your case.  Do something like this in each of your click functions:

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
    $('.div1').toggle(700);

    if ($('.div1').is(':visible')) {
      document.cookie="divnum=1";
      $('.div2').hide();
      $('.div3').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Then just check to see if there's a 'divnum' cookie when you load the page, and if so, open that div instead of the default.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply on this - I'll try these methods and will let you know what worked.

Answer (score 0):

use session storage to set the div id (update it on clicking into each div) and then on page load check the value that is present in session storage and show just the div with that div id - or leave them all visible and scroll to it.

```
 #jdform div{display:none}

 $(document).ready(function(){
        var activeDiv= sessionStorage.getItem('activeDiv');
        if(activeDiv==null){activeDiv='div1'}
        $('#'+activeDiv).css('display','block');
    })

$('div').click(function(){
var activeDiv=$(this).attr('id');
sessionStorage.setItem("activeDiv",activeDiv)
})
```

Comment: the second method worked fine for me: document.cookie="divnum=1"; I was able to allow the web page to toggle back to the user's choice div using this method / storing it in the cookie - thanks again all!